# Insert the proper HTML

Tags: html, tags

Text: Jenny came back, and life was never the same.
Command: Make the words “never the same” italicized.
HTML code:**********************?**********************_______________

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <p> Jenny came back, and life was <i> never the same. </i></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <p>Jenny came back, and life was <i>never the same</i></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

> *never the same*

```html
<p>Jenny came back, and life was <em>never the same.</em></p>
```

as i or em tag is used to italicize any text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your desired code----

Jenny came back, and life was *never the same*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).